# How important is the context that is implied by a namespace?

Tags: c#, .net, namespaces

Ok, the title might sound a bit vague but I really can't think of something clearer here.

I recently was in the position where I needed a `Point` class, simply with two properties, `X` and `Y` and a ctor `Point(int x, int y)`. Nothing fancy. Now this thing already exists in .NET, but this was in a library that handled certain objects on a map and dragging `System.Drawing` into this just felt ... wrong somehow. Even though `System.Drawing.Point` fit what I needed perfectly, I now created that struct myself again in that project.

Now I wonder whether that was a right or sensible thing to do. `System.Drawing.Point` would have come with a reference to that assembly as well, if I remember correctly. And putting something in `System.Drawing` into a totally non-drawing related context was somehow weird.

Thoughts? What if it wouldn't have implied a reference to another assembly?

Comment: To me, its sensible thing to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The context of namespace is fundamental in approaching the precise function of a class; a `Connection` class is going to be a very different beast from one namespace to the next. Is a `Web.Cache` class going to be suitable for caching in other applications, or does it have a fundamental dependency on web infrastructure?

MSDN describes `System.Drawing.Point` structure as follows:

> "Represents an ordered pair of integer x- and y-coordinates that defines a point in a two-dimensional plane."

With such a general description, it could be argued that this structure is only incidentally related to drawing and really belongs in a more fundamental namespace.

However, as it does live in `System.Drawing`, the implication is that it represents a point within a 2-dimensional drawing space. As such, using it for purposes other than drawing is mis-use of the class; it may function for your needs, but it is not being used for its original purpose.

Answer (score 6):

I disagree with the other answers so far and say that it actually matters. The `Point` sample is a simple one, but in general using a class in a context it hasn't been designed for may have undesired effects.

A class may have been implemented for a particular use case only, e.g. no support for thread safety, requiring the use within a framework or exposing functionality that is unwanted in your code.

It might especially lead to problems when a newer version of the assembly is deployed, which is no longer compatible with the way that you use it, or the newer version brings additional members and dependencies that you don't want to have in your code.

Comment: I agree more with this answer. On a related topic, I wan't to point out the comment "Don't Re-Invent the Wheel." Doesn't mean cross namespaces and build spaghetti code. It means if code already exists (that you have control of), and it's common to two projects, abstract it to a higher level of the namespace for re-use.  If it is NOT in the same namespace, and NOT so common that this can be done, then why are you sharing the code? In that example, as implied in your answer, the code that uses it one way may require that it change to be used moreso that way, and will break anybody else using it.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say that what you did was wrong however a namespace is really just a container for declarations within which each name is unique, the namespace name does provide some context to help you find the right function for your need but don't get hung up on the context not quite fitting your useage, if the object is ideal then it's ideal. Apart from the using statement you will probably never actively refer to the namespace again.

Comment: I downvoted from 2 to 1 to help lessen the impact of the answer and hopefully provide more focus to the higher rated answers, because this Q/A is very important.  Especially since this is a very generalized question.  In one specific example, depending on the weight of dependencies and other factors to be taken into consideration, it may indeed be a non-issue as you imply.  But while every developer should be in the mindset of "Don't re-invent the wheel.", I think it's a ver VB style mindset to improperly use namespaces, and should be avoided if possible.

Comment: @Suamere While you are of course entitled to your opinion, this is just your opinion and unless you feel that the answer is in fact incorrect then down-voting it to 'provide balance' is a very strange act. Surely you'd need to down-vote every answer that doesn't fit with your view of 'correct'.

Comment: Yes.  I downvote all answers I disagree with in my opinion and I upvote all answers I agree with in my opinion.  Good observation.  I only happened to comment on yours because you had a good answer, but it wasn't the right answer to this question.

Comment: Well, as long as you are confident in your correctness, however flawed, then I'm sure you will continue in whatever it is you find to do with your time.

Answer (score 1):

If your purpose for the point was in no way drawing related, I think you did the right thing. Using a System.Drawing.Point in code which does nothing drawing related at all may confuse people down the line into thinking it's used for some drawing functionality.

Answer (score 1):

I was in a similar situation recently. Not needing the Point class, but I'll use that as an example.

I made my own Point class because the System.Drawing.Point uses ints, when I needed doubles. I realised later that it was a good idea, even if I only needed ints because I can then extend the class as needed, and add methods, interfaces and attributes etc. Whereas I wouldn't have been able to should I have used the System.Drawing.Point.

There's the principle that you should not duplicate knowledge in your programs, but in some cases such as this one, it can't be avoided.

---

As for implying reference to another assembly, you can do this:

```
using Point = System.Drawing.Point;  // or whatever your namespace is called
```

Comment: For `double`s there's System.Windows.Point, though. Which comes from yet another assembly and yet another subsystem (WPF).

Comment: Oops! Didn't know about that one.

Answer (score 0):

I would have just used the System.Drawing.Point.  Why re-create something that already exists?  Who cares what the namespace is called if provides the functionality you need.  Just my 2 cents...

Answer (score 0):

If you're not importing any "luggage" (like having to intialize stuff that you don't use) so it's exactly what you need, I'd go for the existing code. Just no point in recreating existing code. Chances are also that you may discover functions later on which perform functions you need and expect that particular class.

Still, I can identify with feeling strange having an "alien" object in your code. One way to get around this would be to subclass it with your own point. That'll look a bit strange if you're not changing anything in your subclass, but that's only visible in the source of that class, and where you use it, it's consistently named. Also it'll start looking actually smart as soon as you find yourself adding functionality to your custom Point.

Comment: Having an additional dependency (here to the assembly containing `System.Drawing.Point` is also a sort of extra luggage.

Comment: True. Depends how "heavy" that luggage is compared to your extra coding costs. In the case of Point, reimplementing may actually be ok.

Answer (score 0):

I would worry very little about bringing something in from the namespace given that both functionally and conceptually (how it is described in the docs) it fits the goal.

I might hesitate to bring in a new assembly though. In this case the fact that Point is so quick to roll ones own that I might consider the hassle of doing so less than that of adding another dependency to the assembly I was writing.

Otherwise, as long as I wasn't using it as a Key (the GetHashCode impl. in point isn't great in the way it collides for e.g. all of {0,1},{1,0},{2,3}and{3,2} if you have a lot of low-valued or rectanguarly distributed points) I'd use it.